# Initiating another Kernel?

Tags: kernel

**How can I start a separate kernel** to do other work, while I have Mathematica working on a problem that requires lots of computation time?

I have a program that must be run for many hours, preventing me from working on another project on that session. So I was wondering if it's possible to initiate a new kernel and work on my other projects? What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Go to Evaluation => Kernel Configuration Options => Add Kernel. Then open a new notebook and select which kernel it should use from the menu Evaluation => Notebook's Kernel.

Comment: @Pickett Many Thanks!

Comment: It might be a better solution to start a separate front end as well, for added safety: if your front end crashes, it will also take down all the kernels attached to it.  If you accidentally close the front end, it's the same.  I believe it should be possible to start multiple front ends, but the method should depend on your operating system.  Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm using Win8.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. It took me some time before I could test this, but it appears that on Windows it is possible to launch multiple instances of Mathematica without needing to do anything special.  Whenever I needed to run a long calculation, I did it in a completely separate instance for additional safety (protection against crashes or my own mistakes).