# How to have different $Assumptions for each notebook?

Tags: assumptions

Sometimes I keep two or more notebooks side by side. I noticed that changing $Assumptions in one notebook affects the others, although I have changed Notebook's default context to "Unique to this Notebook".

Is there any walk around of this?

Comment: Just start a separate kernel for each notebook?

Comment: How to do that? Quit kernel and start a new one?

Comment: See C.E.'s commente [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71919/38178) on hwo to do it.

Comment: You can set `CellProlog/Epilog` to set/reset assumptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are less painful way than duplicating the kernel to have `$Assumptions` evaluate to different values.

One way to do it, keeping the context local to each notebook, is to use a supporting variable

```
$Assumptions := ToExpression["myAssumptions"]
```

You can then set the variable in different notebook and it will pick the context automatically

```
myAssumptions = a < 0;
```

If you want to keep the same context among all your notebooks, you can still use the same trick with a small modification

```
getContext[] := 
 StringJoin["Notebook", ToString[Hash[InputNotebook[]]], "`"]

setAssumption[expr_] := (# = expr) &@
  ToExpression[getContext[] <> "myAssumptions", InputForm, Unevaluated]

$Assumptions := ToExpression[getContext[] <> "myAssumptions"]]

setAssumption[a < 0];
```

In the current notebook you will have

```
$Assumptions
(* a < 0 *)
```

while in another notebook you will see something like

```
$Assumptions    
(* Notebook944295401273993393`myAssumptions *)
```

you can then set your different assumptions by doing the same and again `$Assumptions` will pick up the correct one.

```
setAssumption[a > 0];
$Assumptions
(* a > 0 *)
```

You can even get fancier and define a value for when your custom assumptions are not set

```
$Assumptions := 
 If[ValueQ[#], #, True] &@
  ToExpression[getContext[] <> "myAssumptions", InputForm, Unevaluated]
```